# Different results by calculating a geometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate the following sum, but I am getting different results depending on the change of variables I use:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{2n}$$

If I make the change of variables $R=r^2$, I get the following result (which, according to Wolfram Alpha, is correct):

$$S=\frac{r^2}{1-r^2}$$

If instead I make the change of variables $m=2n$, I get the following result:

$$S'=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}r^{m}=-r^0-r^1+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}r^{m}=\frac{r^2}{1-r}$$

Why doesn't this second change of variables work?

Comment: It doesn't work because when you substitute $m=2n$, you should not sum over all the $m$, but only over the even ones.

Comment: Notice that you're then summing different terms. With $n$, the indices are
$$
n = 1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots 
$$
which correspond to $r^{2\cdot 1}, r^{2\cdot 2}, r^{2\cdot 3}$ etc. But with $m$, you're summing
$$
m=2, 3, 4, \ldots 
$$
which corresponds to $r^2, r^3, r^4, \ldots$ That's a different sum.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the sums you presented are different. Substituting a variable in sums, should be with the index in mind.

---

In this case, the proper way to simplify the sequence of the sum, by using substitution is to let $r^2 = p \iff r^{2n} = (r^2)^n$

Hence, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  p^n = \frac{p}{1-p} \stackrel{p=r^2}{=} \frac{r^2}{1-r^2}$$